# How to generate a group route in Lumen that doesn't throw a 500 error?

Tags: lumen

In my web.php file, this route works:

```
$router->post('api/v1/token', 'APITokens@createToken');
```

These do not:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function($router) {
    $router->post('token', 'APITokens@createToken');
});
```

Or:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->post('token', 'APITokens@createToken');
});
```

In the group for $router, it returns this error:

*Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\APITokens does not exist*

Note the doubling-up of the path "App\Http\Controllers"

In the second example it throws a 500 error: Undefined variable: app

In the first argument to post, using either example, putting a leading "/" before "token" has no effect.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

For the $router->group() function, remove the namespace argument as param 2 - now the controller method procs correctly and returns the expected results.  Also, doesn't matter if "token" has a leading slash or not in the first argument to post().

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function($router) {
    $router->post('token', 'APITokens@createToken');
});
```